# Create site collection in content database

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, site-collection

I want to set by default to create a site collection in an independent content database when creating a new site collection automatically!

Ex: each content database only holds one site collection by default!

Is it possible to do that automatically without using code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible automatically.

> **Unfortunately,** There is no event receiver triggered when creating/ created a site collection to handle this using event receiver.

---

**However,** you can adjust this manually by **locking down** the content database as the following:

**Steps**

Before creating a new site collection, you should plan to do the following:

- Lockdown all the web application content databases.
- Create a new independent content database for the new Site Collection.

  [image]
- Create a new Site Collection will be created inside the newly created content database.

Check also [Lockdown the web application content databases](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/28/lock-down-the-project-web-app-content-database/)

---

**Another workaround**

Using **PowerShell** to [Create a SharePoint Site Collection in an Independent Content Database](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50903.powershell-create-a-sharepoint-site-collection-in-an-independent-content-database.aspx)

**Download** the full script at [PowerShell: Create a SharePoint Site Collection in a Separate Content Database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Create-a-8776a51c)

Comment: @Tomaz be aware that this is not correct and it is possible to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, but your answer is not doable in my situation, I need to do it automatically and your answer requires code too, I think Mohamed answer is the correct one, I cannot do this automatically without code! The lockdown solution is the best one in my case!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible by overriding the class [SPSiteCreationProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecreationprovider). With this, you can select all of your existing content databases. If you cannot find a content database in the web application that meets the criteria, you could then create a new content database.

You should be aware that this would slow down the site creation process significantly as provisioning a new content database isn't an instant process.

I'm linking to Wictor's article below which references HNSC, but this will also apply to path-based site collections.

[SharePoint: Specifying Content Database for new Site Collections when using Host Named Site Collections](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-specifying-content-database-for-new-site-collections-when-using-host-named-site-collections)